# Can I modify function wrapper so that it uses its old value?

Tags: c++, c++11

Can I modify function wrapper like this

```
std::function<int(int)> a=[](int x){return 2*x;};
a=[f=a](int x){return f(x)+1;};
```

so I can dynamically build more and more complex functions?

Comment: why don't you try it? [yes it works](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/b9tqEV2qJOyMKZeE)

Comment: What are possible problems with that?

Comment: You tagged this C++11, so no. *init-capture* is C++14.

Comment: @T.C. Well, could just do `a = [a](int x){ return a(x) + 1; };` and accomplish the same thing, if somewhat more confusingly.

Comment: @Barry Sure, my point is that the code, as written, won't compile in a C++11 compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work primarily because initializer expressions were introduced in C++14.

However this is valid syntax in C++14. Here is some evidence: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fe0a53953b0421b